# Begin Dialog with QnA Maker Bot Framework recognizer (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I was wondering if one can pass a "Welcome Message" on the beginning of a chat with a bot using QnA Maker recognizer without the model recognizing it as message to send to the model. I'm using the latest Node.js API.

```
var intents = new builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
                    recognizers: [recognizer],
                    defaultMessage: 'Sorry. I didnt understand',
                    qnaThreshold: 0.3}
    );
    bot.dialog('/', [
        function(session){
            session.beginDialog('welcome');
        },
        function(session){
            session.beginDialog('dialog');
        }
    ]);

    bot.dialog('welcome', [
        function (session) {
            // Send a greeting and show help.
            session.send("Hi! How can I help you?");
            session.endDialog();
        }
    ]);

    bot.dialog('dialog', intents);
```

Like this, my bot is sending the `session.send("Hi! How can I help you?")`; to the QnA Model and replying "Sorry. I didnt understand".

With **LUIS** I don't have this issue only with the `QnAMakerDialog`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code gives you the behavior you're looking for.

```
bot.dialog('welcome', [
    function (session) {
        // Send a greeting and show help.
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Hi! How can I help you?");
    }
]);
```

I think it's falling through because `session.send` followed by `session.endDialog` is not waiting for the user and it falls through.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and give feedback asap