# Microsoft QnA maker - Welcome message loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to achieve something similar to what has been done on this topic
[Begin Dialog with QnA Maker Bot Framework recognizer (Node JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629688/begin-dialog-with-qna-maker-bot-framework-recognizer-node-js)

The suggestion works as per having the bot sending first a welcome message, then waiting for the questions. 
However the bot now Says 'Hj! How can I help you?", waits for the questions, then it comes back to the welcome again.

Something like

A: Hi! How can I help you?
Q: What is the number for Car repair
A: Call 500-XXXX etc..
Q: Who should I contact for vacation days?
A: Hi! How can I help you?

I played with beginDialog, End conversation, replace conversation.. however with no luck.

This is the latest code.

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session ) {
          session.beginDialog('/welcome');
        }, 
    function (session)  {
        session.beginDialog('/qna');
}
]) ;



bot.dialog('/welcome', [
        function (session) {
            // Send a greeting and show help.
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "Hi! How can I help you?");
            //  session.endDialog();
        }
    ]);


bot.dialog('/qna',  basicQnAMakerDialog   ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code example showing how to listen for the `conversationUpdate` event that is fired when a new user connects to the bot. Aka the "welcome message":

```
// Listen for 'conversationUpdate' event to detect members joining conversation.
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id == message.address.bot.id) {
                // Bot is joining conversation
                // - For WebChat channel you'll get this on page load.
                var reply = new builder.Message()
                        .address(message.address)
                        .text("Welcome to my page");
                bot.send(reply);
            } else {
                // User is joining conversation
                // - For WebChat channel this will be sent when user sends first message.
                // - When a user joins a conversation the address.user field is often for
                //   essentially a system account so to ensure we're targeting the right 
                //   user we can tweek the address object to reference the joining user.
                // - If we wanted to send a private message to teh joining user we could
                //   delete the address.conversation field from the cloned address.
                var address = Object.create(message.address);
                address.user = identity;
                var reply = new builder.Message()
                        .address(address)
                        .text("Hello %s", identity.name);
                bot.send(reply);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however this does not solve the issue. The dialog still follow the same pattern: Welcome Message , answer, then Welcome mesagge again.. I would love to be able to show the welcome message only once.